# what kind of code can damage my site

Tags: html, tags

I want to make sure rogue users can't damage my site or database by inserting code in my input fields.
What kind of code should I use to test it?
I know there are html tags like iframe but I don't know what to put inside to test it.

Thanks.

Comment: +1 - not sure why someones down voted you, as I'd have thought that it was a legitimate question by a new user. Although could have been better phrased as looking for pointers on web page security best practice.

Comment: What database are you using? What webtechnology is the site based on?

Comment: Thanks for the +1. I use MS SQL server with asp. Actually, I'm relating more to a chat window than an input field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### HTML

I think using `htmlspecialchars`([doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)) (It's a function in PHP but other language may has similar function) or using other markup system(?)s like phpBB and MediaWiki would be work. Using HTML tags by black/whitelisting tags can work but it's quite dangerous - a cracker would harm your site by XSSing.

For example, you may think that only allowing `p`, `br`, `img`, `font`, `a` is OK (BTW, it's not good to use `font` when one can use CSS), but XSS can be done by input `<img src="asdf" onerror="alert('hi')"/>` or `<a href="javascript:alert('hi')">`.

### SQL

You should aware of SQLi - injecting SQL commands.

An example of SQLi is :

[image]

A way to avoid being SQLi'd in PHP is using `mysql_real_escape_string`([doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)).

Comment: An alternative way to avoid SQL injections is using *prepared statements*.

Answer (score 1):

You could read about [SQL Injections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Comment: Thanks. What about html tags?

Answer (score 1):

Insert special characters, especially `'`, `?`, `"`, `$`, `;`, `,` and `\`. If your site doesn't fail on those, you're on the right track.

But the best is to use queries with parameters. You just pass the string as a parameter and the database takes care of escaping the characters for you. You can hardly make a mistake if you do that.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the architecture and user interaction with your site.
SQL injection into user entered fields is a typical attack on systems that use databases for user logins etc. Hence restrictions on characters entered into user fields and screening them before use.

"About your son ..."
"Oh Little Billy !drop tables ?"